# HTML elements with IDs in the global context

Tags: javascript, html

If I declare an HTML element with an ID, I can access it via a property on the `globalThis`:

```js
console.log(globalThis.foo) // <div id="foo"></div>
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

...but if I do `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'foo')` I get `undefined`.

Why?

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'foo')) // undefined
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

The only answer I can think of is that a proxy is defined on `window`.

Comment: Why the downvote though?

Comment: Sounds like `globalThis` inherits `foo` from some other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [MDN docs for `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) it states in the first paragraph that only properties directly present on the object will return a valid property descriptor. So it won't return a valid property descriptor if the property is either a) defined on the objects prototype (or its prototype, recursive) or b) defined in native code. <s>Which is most likely the case this with `globalThis`.</s>

> The Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() method returns a property descriptor for an own property (that is, one directly present on an object and not in the object's prototype chain) of a given object.

As @52d6c6af figured out in the comments, DOM elements with IDs are defined on the WindowProperties object, which is part of the prototype chain of the window object.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.__proto__.__proto__, 'foo'))
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

---

Also, as a rule of thumb. Don't use `globalThis` or `window` to access DOM elements. Use `getElementById` or `querySelector`.

```js
const foo0 = globalThis.foo;
const foo1 = document.getElementById('foo');
const foo2 = document.querySelector('#foo');

console.log(foo0 === foo1, foo1 === foo2);
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: All host and intrinsic objects are "defined in native code". `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` works with them. eg. `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(globalThis, 'localStorage'))`

Comment: @52d6c6af How does that address Olian04's answer?

Comment: @52d6c6af `localstorage` in and of it self IS defined in native code. However the key "localstorage" on the `globalThis` object is a ordinary JS reference to the `localhost` object. (Bear in mind I'm not an engine developer so lets call these educated guesses)

Comment: @j08691 My comment addresses the following line in the answer: "a) defined on the objects prototype (or its prototype, recursive) **or b) defined in native code.**" (my emphasis).

Comment: I've found where DOM nodes with ISs are added. There is a `WindowProperties` object on the prototype chain of `window` (`window.__proto__.__proto__`). I do not know if this is part of the Web standard, but it is present on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. If you add this information to your answer, I will accept it.